# как работает функция int GetHashCode (object obj)

Tags: c#

Как работает эта функция  `int GetHashCode()`, и что означает вообще хеш-код для объекта?

Answer (score 2):

В классе object (реализация по умолчанию) этот метод работает примерно так: при создании объекта под него забивается число, и метод GetHashCode возвращает это число.

Хэш-код необходим для структур данных, поддерживающих поиск по ключу (HashSet, Dictionary). Поскольку это целое число, по хэш-кодам данные разбиваются, формируя сбалансированное дерево, позволяющее максимально быстро сделать поиск. При поиске перебираются не все объекты, а только те, у которых хэш-код совпадает с хэш-кодом искомого объекта.

Хэш-код используется для сортировки в сбалансированном дереве. Для поиска используется метод Equals. Необходимо придерживаться следующего правила: если Equals при сравнении двух объектов вернул true, то их хэш-коды должен быть одинаковыми. Два одинаковых хэш-кода могут быть у не эквивалентных объектов.

Comment: Верно, однако не сбалансированное дерево. `Dictionary<Tkey, TValue>`, к примеру, реализован как Хэш-таблица, именно для этого и служат хэш-коды. Для реализации словаря как красно-чёрного дерева есть `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.